# fullCalendar using eventAllow to restrict event based on given DateTime

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to restrict my events so that they can only be dropped before a given time which is within each event. when i drop before the date, it works perfectly. however, when i drop after the given date the event disappears; what am I missing?I'm using ASP.NET MVC to populate my calendar.

My code:

```
        $("#calendar")
        .fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: "agendaWeek month",
                center: "title",
                right: "prev, today, next"
            },
            defaultView: "agendaWeek",
            //click on a day in the month view to go to that week
            dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
                if (view.name === "month") {
                    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("changeView", "agendaWeek");
                    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("gotoDate", date);
                }
            },
            editable: true,
            timeFormat: "H:mm",
            droppable: true,
            timezone: "Europe/London",
            eventLimit: true,
            eventSources: [

                "/Home/GetCalendar"
            ],
            dragRevertDuration: 0,
            allDaySlot: false,
            minTime: "07:00:00",
            firstDay: 1,
            aspectRatio: 1.97,
            //this moves events from tray to calendar
            drop: function (date, jsEvent, ui, resourceId) {
                UpdateEvent($(this).attr("uniqueId"), date);
                $(this).remove();
            },
            eventDragStop: function (event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
                //if the event is hovering over the tray
                if (isEventOverDiv(jsEvent.clientX, jsEvent.clientY)) {
                    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("removeEvents", event.uniqueId);
                    //adds to the panel 
                    UpdateEvent(event.uniqueId, "");
                }
            },
            //adds description underneath title
            eventRender: function (event, element) {
                if (event.location !== "") {
                    element.find(".fc-content").append(event.location);
                } else {
                    element.find(".fc-content").append(event.assignmentName + "<p>" + event.moduleName + "</p>");
                }
                element.find(".fc-content").qtip({content: {
                    text: event.details
                }});
            },
            //this sends a pop up to confirm the drop - probably don't need all the time
            eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
                if (confirm("Confirm move?")) {
                    UpdateEvent(event.uniqueId, event.start);
                } else {
                    revertFunc();
                }
                //UpdateEvent(event.uniqueId, event.start);
            },
            eventAllow: function (dropLocation, draggedEvent) {
                var day = moment(draggedEvent.dueDate);
                if (dropLocation.start > day) {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            eventClick: function (event) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/Home/EditEventView",
                    data: { eventId: event.uniqueId },
                    success: function (response) {
                        ModalControl("#editEventModal");
                        $("#editEventModal").html(response);
                    }
                });
            },
            theme: true
        });
```

edit:

my events are passed to my calendar with a feed using asp.net (mvc) and Json. some context, this app is for a calendar for university students. i left out fetching from database using entity framework but basically it populates a list of events and then i pass a new list as shown below.
code:

```
            var newRows = rows.Select(e => new
        {
            uniqueId = e.EventId,
            title = e.Title,
            start = e.StartTime,
            end = e.EndTime,
            details = e.Details,
            location = e.Location,
            className = e.ClassName,
            editable = e.Editable,
            module = e.Module.ModuleId,
            assignment = e.Assignment.AssignmentId,
            assignmentName = e.Assignment.Title,
            moduleName = e.Module.ModuleName,
            color = e.Module.Color,
            dueDate = e.DueDate
        }).ToList();
        return Json(newRows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of an event that you're dragging and dropping?

Comment: added some changes to show how i get events? is this what you mean?

Comment: In "eventAllow": `if (dropLocation.start > day) {` is potentially unreliable. MomentJs provides specific methods for comparing dates which cover all cases, where the standard JS operators might not work properly. `if (dropLocation.start.isAfter(day)) {` will be more accurate. Also, you must explicitly return true/false from this function in all cases. Simply doing `return !dropLocation.start.isAfter(day);` (instead of the if statement) will give the necessary response. Try these changes and see if you still have an issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! I applied your changes as they are cleaner than my solution, however they didn't fix the problem. I've been fiddling and tried disabling my drop property, which has now made it work correctly, however I need the drop property for my external events. also even when not disabled its not hitting the breakpoint i have placed on the drop function/property.

Comment: that's odd because the drag/drop of existing (internal) events is entirely separate to the drag/drop of external events. They're handled by different callbacks and also implemented differently (assuming you use fullCalendar >= 2.1.0). When you say it "stops working" when "droppable" is "true", at what point does it fail exactly? Do you get any errors in your browser console? Also, your functionality for external events appears to be incomplete - it doesn't seem to check whether the date is allowed

Comment: I haven't implemented if the date is allowed for external yet, as this is a new feature, I was more trying to get internal to work first, and then work on external. (I'll probably use dropAccept for external, that seems the easiest way). I changed back just to see if there was a console error, and you are right, there was an 500 error posting an UpdateEvent method. either way, it seems that changing the class name to external has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So found a fix. Basically as I was using external events, I had a Javascript method which allowed div's I'd created to be dragged from a tray on the side into the calendar. I was using the class draggable which conflicted within the calendars own use of the class draggable, so it was getting confused. I renamed the class that is used when getting tray items to "external" and this seems to have fixed the problem

```
function EnableDragging() {
  $(".external").each(function () {
    $(this).draggable({
        zIndex: 999,
        revert: true,
        revertDuration: 0
    });
  });
}
```